# How to make Django pass cookies when communicating with Node.js server using socket.io?

Tags: django, node.js, sockets, cookies

I am currently developing an instant messaging feature for my apps (ideally cross platform mobile app/web app), and I am out of ideas to fix my issue.
So far, I have been able to make everything work locally, using a Node.js server with socket.io, django, and redis, following what most tutorials online suggest.
The step I am now at consists in putting all that in the cloud using amazon AWS. My Django server is up and running, I created a new separate Node.js server, and I am using Elasticache to handle the Redis part. I launch the different parts, and no error shows up.
However, whenever I try using my messaging feature on the web, I keep getting an error 500:

handshake error

I then used the console to check the request header, and I observed that the cookies are not in there, contrary to when I am on localhost. I know it is necessary to authorize the handshake, so I guess that's where my error is coming from..

Furthermore, I have also checked that the cookies do exist, they are just not set in the request header.

My question is then: How can I make sure Django or socket client (not sure who's responsible here..) puts the cookies in the header??

One of my ideas was that maybe I am supposed to put everything on the same server, with different ports, instead of 2 separate servers? Documentation on that specific architecture problem is surprisingly scarce, compared to the number of tutorials describing how to make it work on local.

I hope I described the problem accurately enough! :)

Important note: I am using socket.io v0.9.1-1, only one compatible with a titanium mobile app.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, so I've made some progress.
The cookie problem came from the fact I was making cross-domain request, adding a few lines enabled CORS, which didn't solve the cookie issue, but allowed me to communicate between servers (basically I set the headers of the response using `express`. I then passed necessary data in the query, even if not the most secure way to do it, I'm just building an MVP, and it's enough for now.

I haven't been able to make the chat work from my Titanium mobile app, but since I can use a webview to handle it, I will be fine.

Hopefully that will help someone.. If anyone needs me to post some code snippets I will gladly do so upon request!

Cheers

Comment: I got it working on mobile as well: I forced socket to use xhr-polling. My guess is that Nginx and websockets are not yet close friends, and without some knowledge about configuring Nginx, making a websocket connection behind Nginx is a pain. So I added `io.set('transports',['xhr-polling']);` server-side, to prevent websocket errors from happening.